# Burn ETH from balance of contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I have a contract that is funded with ETH. I want to simulate a burn of ETH when a given condition is met. Is the following an acceptable way of burning ETH?

```
//Burn ether simulating payment of monthly rent
address burn = address(0x00);
burn.transfer(rentalAmount);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "simulate a burn of ETH", but the code you have will actually burn ETH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Burning means losing it forever in a provable way.

A right way to burn ether is sending it to an address which you don't have the private key.

Others can't be sure if you have the private key or not, unless you send it to a special address, like 0x0. So when you send ether to 0x0, we call it burning.